# Get file information on Windows right click menu item click in c#

Tags: c#, file-io, network-printers

I have a printershare like application that will send files over network. When a file is selected (in Windows Explorer via a right click) our application menu item will be present. On Clicking that it should display a form with the selected document/file information in order to process the print function.

How am i able to get the file info in this scenario. Is there any windows api that will return the  selected file information?

Comment: Please show.What you have already searched for that?

Comment: @ShoaibMuhammadKhan: I was searching using tags like 'get file info on windows menu right click + C# ' but end up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a code sample project called [Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/). Its code samples target programming tasks that are frequently asked by developers. The team is working on a series of .NET 4 managed Shell extension code samples for **Context Menu Handler**, Property Sheet Handler, Icon handler, Data handler, Drop handler, Drag-and-drop handler, Thumbnail Handler, Icon Handler, Icon Overlay Handler, and so on. see `CSShellExtContextMenuHandler`.

See these linkes also:

- [Writing Windows Shell Extension with .NET Framework 4 (C#, VB.NET) - Part 1: Context Menu Handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx) *msdn*
- [Simple shell context menu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15171/Simple-shell-context-menu) *codeproject*

Comment: Thanks @Ria. This might be of help. Will check and get back.
check this column regularly. :)

Comment: The 'Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework' link goes to a page saying this: "Project '1code' was not found" ... sadly.